# How to show a JPopupMenu without stealing focus?

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I am writing a program in Java Swing and in this program there will be a search bar (which will be a JTextField), and when there is something typed into this field I want to display the search results in a popup menu directly underneath the search bar, like Google does. I haven't got to actually populating the menu with the search results (I currently have a test menu with fixed items), I am stuck on the problem that everytime a new character is typed into the field focus is taken away from the field and onto the popup menu. I am using

```
show(Component invoker, int x, int y)
```

to display the menu, with the invoker being the text field or the containing box. And as I said, everytime this function is called the popup menu takes the focus away from the text box which is a big problem. Instead of using this show method I could use these:

```
setLocation(int x, int y)
setVisible(boolean b)
```

However without an invoker the popup menu isn't shown relative to the search bar, and when I use setInvoker(Component invoker) I have the same problem as with the show method. I can't set the invoker during initialization because the invoker isn't visible then. So how do I create this popupMenu with an invoker without taking focus away from the search text field? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: The "main" reason focus is lost is because something in the popup is stealing it. AFAIK, `JPopupMenu` doesn't tend to change focus by itself. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `requestFocusInWindow()`?  I think you need to give the focus back to the search text field at the end of the popup menu code.  I assume you have some code to create the popup menu.  Add `searchTextField.requestFocusInWindow()` to the end of this code.  If this doesn't help, then I need more information.  Some more code would help.

Comment: Doing requestFocusInWindow() right after show/setInvoker works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
popup.setFocusable(false);
```

worked for me